# Shared library error when using rsync

Tags: arch-linux, rsync, openssl, shared-library

I'm trying to transfer a folder from a backup location to my `$HOME` folder but I keep getting the error:

```
rsync: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/` to my `.bashrc`, `echo "/usr/lib64" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mylibs.conf; sudo ldconfig` etc. but to no avail.

I know I have the package installed, since `pacman -F libcrypto.so.3` returns

```
core/openssl 3.0.7-2 [installed: 1.1.1.q-1]
    usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3
multilib/lib32-openssl 1:3.0.7-1 [installed]
    usr/lib32/libcrypto.so.3
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Can this be caused by a bug in OpenSSL or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `pacman -F` shows you don't have the latest version of OpenSSL installed. A common reason for an error message such as the one you posted is that a program (here, rsync) was installed without performing a full system upgrade, which is [the only supported way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported) on Arch Linux.

Maybe you just need do upgrade your system with `pacman -Syu`.